# What is this strange construction?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *Othello*, as with any other play by W. Shakespeare, is much of the savour of human complexity. He presents a diversity of psychological specimens, through which can we, **if ever so** inclined, essay to plumb the consciousness of the era, age, epoch in which we happen, at a given time, to find ourselves.

What does the bolded part mean?

Comment: Please tell us what the source of your quote is.

Comment: @snailplane it is from my translation workbook...the grammar is wrong ? I consulted my grammar book but these points are not there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not written in contemporary English. What is the author and date?

> Othello, as with any other play by W. Shakespeare, **is much of the savour** of human complexity. He presents a diversity of psychological specimens, through which **can we**, if **ever so inclined**, **essay to** plumb the consciousness of the era, age, epoch in which we happen, at a given time, to find ourselves.

Current English:

> Othello, as with any other play by W. Shakespeare, **about the richness** of human complexity. He presents a diversity of psychological specimens, through which **we can**, if **we wish**, **attempt to** plumb the consciousness of the era, age, epoch in which we happen, at a given time, to find ourselves.

Even after updating these phrases, the way of using the word  'specimens' to describe people and choice of words like 'plumbs' still indicate that this is either old writing or is intentionally trying to sound old.

"If ever" here means "if (we) (are) ever."

So "if ever troubled" would mean "if you are ever troubled".

"So inclined" means "of the attitude (which I implicitly stated earlier, or you can guess)." So "we can eat, if so inclined" would mean "we can eat, if we wish to eat" -- e.g. we can eat if we are hungry.

"if ever" / "so inclined": if we are ever feeling the desire to, if we are ever wish to, if we are ever in the mood to.

Comment: so this inversion "can we..." is grammatical?

Comment: the whole sentence is grammatical?

Comment: No. It may have been grammatical centuries ago, but the inversion "through which can we" does not make sense as contemporary spoken and written English. Examples of using "can we" to mean "we can" in this way will usually come from old language, like a Shakespeare play ("Nothing **can we** call our own but death." Richard II, ~1595).

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion here might come from the fact that the "so" goes with "inclined".

"So" can sometimes mean "that way" or "this way" (think "make it so"), so "so inclined" can mean "inclined that way" or "felt drawn that way" (as if "that way" were at the bottom of a slope or incline).

The structure "If *subject* ever *verb*" can be re-ordered as "If ever *subject* *verb*", although it's not as common, and can sound old-fashioned or overly formal.

In this case, the odd overall structure allows the subject to be the "we" from "through which can we" so the whole thing works out to "if we ever felt drawn that way".

Answer (score -2):

"if (we were) ever so inclined..."

Broadly paraphrasing here, "He presents such range of characters and characteristics, that **if we wanted to**, we could try to access the time period and find ourselves."

Comment: Broadly paraphrasing here, "He presents such range of characters and characteristics, that if we wanted to, we could try to access the time period and find ourselves."

Comment: Hello and welcome to Learners. Your comment answers the question well, so I've copied it into the text of your answer. Feel free to [edit] it further or to roll it back. (Comments on Stack Exchange are considered ephemeral and may be deleted without notice; question and answer blocks are treated with more respect.)